# HTML5 <video> element not playing in iOS

Tags: html, ios, google-cloud-storage, html5-video

- I have an `.mp4` video uploaded to Google Cloud Storage.
- I'm using a `<video>` element to play it on my website.
- It loads on desktop, but **not** iOS. (not yet tested with Android)

#### Code

```
<video muted autoplay loop playsinline>
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/FILE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In the **Resources** tab of Safari's web inspector, the video file has an error saying:

- "An error occurred trying to load the resource"

Could this be a CORS issue?

It's worth noting that visiting the video url directly (using iOS Safari) works as expected, so I assume the video encoding is fine.

Comment: Are you using UIWebView?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed No, I'm serving an `.html` file to an iOS Safari user.

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS Chrome either (which uses `WKWebView`).

Comment: This is weird! Did you try another video?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed I tried using [this video](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4) but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a negative `z-index` causing the parent element to be hidden.

Strangely, it only caused the issue on iOS and not desktop browsers.

Comment: Things like this wont always be the case -- i have a static site using video tags uploaded to netlify. it works everywhere except desktop/mobile safari (this mean it also works in ios chrome/ios ff). In my case the issue comes from netlify's CDN as we saw issues with the ranged requests where the 1st was okay, 2nd failed, 3rd and 4th were fine.

Comment: @StephenTetreault You wouldn't think the browser would make a difference, since all iOS browsers use the same Webkit engine. Interesting.

Comment: 100% agree with you @aleclarson, totally frustrating. I could confirm it was netlify, and have since moved all my site content to aws s3 and have no issues whatsoever.

Comment: i resolved the issue btw. it was unrelated to anything in this thread. I'm building a webapp with the vuejs Nuxt. Nuxt is great, but i decided to use their new PWA module. Service workers/html5 video/safari dont play well. The issue of ranged requests failing is not specific to this Nuxt module, i've also tracked down an angularJS github issue thread well documented that describes the exact same thing. So future readers -- if you encounter this, check your PWA module.